# Check if an application is mvc, WebForms or both

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, model-view-controller, webforms

At my work, I was given an application which is developed in Visual Studio 2012. Admittedly, I don't know very much about VS or vb.NET.

Could anybody tell me how to check if the application is written to MVC, WebForms or both?

Cheers

Comment: As a start if the solution contains Models,Controllers and Views Folder, it is very likely it is MVC.

Comment: You can also look at which namespace is included... or you know, ask for a crash course on how the application operate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the webpages have a `.aspx` extension, they're web forms. If they are `.vbhtml` files, then they're MVC. Also, look for folders called `Models`, `Views`, and `Controllers` as @apomene noted. It is possible to have both WebForms and MVC features in one single project. Check out [this page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381619(v=vs.98).aspx).